# Orden de horas datetime en consulta php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

Descargo unos datos de un api, entre esos campos traigo fecha y hora separados. Al hacer el insert en la base uno la fecha y hora mas 00:00 para transformarla en datetime, el detalle es que la hora 24 se transforma en 00 esto hace que el ultimo valor pase a ser el primero a mostrar.

Asi hago la consulta de los datos y el insert a la base.

```
$json = json_decode($pagina_inicio, true);// se guarda en json la consulta del api
        foreach($json as $dato) {
            if(is_array($dato)){
                foreach ($dato as $datos => $value) {
                    if(is_array($value)){
                        $clv_nodo = $value['clv_nodo'];
                        foreach ($value as $key => $value2) {
                            if(is_array($value2)){
                                foreach ($value2 as $key2 => $value3) {
                                    if(is_array($value3)){
                                        $fecha = $value3['fecha'];
                                        $hora = $value3['hora'];
                                        if($hora=="24")//cuando la hora es =24 la cambia en 00 
                                        $hora="00";
                                        $pml_mda = $value3['pml'];
                                        $ene_mda = $value3['pml_ene'];
                                        $per_mda = $value3['pml_per'];
                                        $cong_mda = $value3['pml_cng'];
                                        $datetime= $fecha.' '.$hora.':00:00';//se crea el campo datetime a partir de la union de la fecha y hora mas 00:00
                                        $fecha_unix_og= strtotime($datetime);
                                        $horas='25200';
                                        $fecha_unix= $fecha_unix_og + $horas;
                                        $identificador = $fecha_unix.'-'.$clv_nodo;
                                        $nodo = $clv_nodo;
                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO node_data (fecha_unix,clv_nodo,pml_mda,per_mda,cong_mda,ene_mda,identificador,fechahora) 
                                        VALUES('$fecha_unix','$nodo','$pml_mda','$per_mda','$cong_mda','$ene_mda','$identificador','$datetime')";
                                        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
                                        {
                                            echo "$nodo----------------".$fecha.' '.$hora.':00:00'."<br>";
                                        } else 
                                            {
                                              echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                                            }
                                        }
```

Despues de insertados los campos me quedan ordenados asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es ¿De que forma puedo ordenar la consulta o hacer el insert para que el valor 00 se muestre despues de las 23:00:00?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que al representarlo en una grafica la primera hora que muestra seria la 24 transformada en 00.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UPDATE:
Así es como lo requiero. Aqui agregue el campo hora para ordenarlo pero no se como ordenarlo del 1 al 24 por cada dia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es la consulta? Cuál es el insert? Edita tu pregunta y complétala, por favor

Comment: Disculpa con gusto. La complemento.

Comment: Por lo que veo, este sistema tratar de reinventar la rueda ¿esa API devuelve las horas así?: `01:00` a `24:59`? El día comienza a las `00:00` y termina a las `23:59`, Mysql y lenguajes trabajan naturalmente con ese orden. Por ejemplo, la hora `24:35` no existe. Si quieres continuar así, una opción puede ser guardar ese dato directo como viene de la API en un `varchar`, junto con el `24:00:00`.

Comment: Hola, si amigo las horas me las manda del 1-24 solamente siendo la hora 1 la primera y la 24 la ultima, como vi que ya me traia fecha y hora decidi agregar esas columnas y ordenarlas por fecha y hora eso lo soluciona

Answer (score 0):

Como lo solucione para bien o mal funciono, al ver que ya tenia la fecha (YYYY-mm-dd) y el campo hora (int(2)) lo que hice fue agregar esas dos columnas y hacer el select ordenado por fecha,hora.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]